# Is it a bad practice that FooManager calls Foo.OnSthHappened()?

Tags: oop, events, design-patterns, inheritance

In my project there is a document management system. There is a base `Document` class and some derived classes. There is also a `DocumentManager` class which manages the open/close/activate operations of documents.

The `Document` and its derived classes may want to do something upon being loaded, closed, etc, but the state change is controlled by the manager class, so currently there are (virtual) methods like `OnLoaded()`, `OnClosed()` on the `Document` class called by the `DocumentManager` class. It works fine except exposing these methods to public seems unnecessary.

An alternative design is to make `DocumentManager` class firing events and each `Document` instance subscribe to these events. IMHO it doesn't make a big difference yet introduces the risk of memory leak.

I have a gut feeling that none of these is "the solution" and there is a best practice  right for the problem. Can someone enlighten me please?

Comment: Manger, Handler etc term does not state the functionality of the class. And should be avoided.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this. Are you saying that DocumentManager doesn't describe the functionality of the class and therefore it should be named something different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My gut feeling, though it's difficult to be sure without knowing the specific requirements of your project, is that you've got logic in your `DocumentManager` class which should probably be in the sub-classes of your `Document` class.

I would imagine a (potentially abstract) `Document` base class with public `load`, `close` and `whatever` methods. Each sub-class would implement those methods according to its specific requirements allowing you to easily create any number of `Document` sub-classes, without the logic in the `DocumentManager` needing to change (see [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29)). If those operations are asynchronous, your `Document` classes would dispatch events to inform the `DocumentManager` that they had completed.

This would leave the `DocumentManager` with the [single responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) of managing (I'm assuming) its collection of `Document` instances.